# Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[mysql-devel]

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I ran a recipe to install the mysql-client and mysql-server on my rhel6 linux box. The recipes used were downloaded from supermarket using knife tool.
i am following [this](http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/first-steps-with-chef.html) tutorial step by step.
on executing this command:

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json
```

====

**I got the following error.**

```
Recipe: mysql::client
  * package[mysql] action install (up to date)
  * package[mysql-devel] action install

================================================================================
**Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[mysql-devel]'**
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
 returned 1, expected 0


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/subham/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/client.rb

 47:   package name
 48: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /home/subham/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/client.rb:47:in `block in from_file'

package("mysql-devel") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "mysql-devel"
  version "5.1.61-4.el6"
  timeout 900
  cookbook_name :mysql
  recipe_name "client"
end


Running handlers:
[2014-11-26T06:22:23-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2014-11-26T06:22:23-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-11-26T06:22:23-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 29.10138575 seconds
[2014-11-26T06:22:24-05:00] ERROR: package[mysql-devel] (mysql::client line 47) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0
[2014-11-26T06:22:24-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

**Stacktrace at /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out**

```
Generated at 2014-11-26 06:22:23 -0500
Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[mysql-devel] (mysql::client line 47) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:158:in `handle_command_failures'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1021:in `yum_command'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1136:in `install_package'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:156:in `converge_by'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:121:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource.rb:648:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:226:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:33:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:33:in `<main>'
```

**File at /home/subham/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/client.rb**

```
line 46 : node['mysql']['client']['packages'].each do |name|
line 47 :   package name
line 48 : end
```

**In the header comment section of the same file**

```
# Include Opscode helper in Recipe class to get access
# to debian_before_squeeze? and ubuntu_before_lucid?
```

Does it mean that this recipe will only work in debian family based systems like ubuntu and not in RHEL or fedora/Cent OS ?
If yes then what changes i need to perform ?

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more of output, here we can see what's failed but there is no info about why and what happened?

Comment: Please add the contents of `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` so we can see the full traceback.

Comment: Or crank up logging with `chef-solo -l debug -c solo.rb -j web.json` to see if it gives you the command that fails

Comment: @coderanger , i ran the exact recipe on my ubuntu machine and it worked. earlier i was using RHEL 6. i will be posting stacktrace soon.

Comment: So that awkward leading space in the error means the command it tried to run was literally "". I don't see any way that can happen in the yum package provider so something else is amiss.

Comment: @coderanger , sorry but i cant see it. where are you pointing to ?

Comment: `" returned 1, expected 0"`. Note the leading space. The format string used to create that is `"#{opts[:command]} returned #{status.exitstatus}, expected #{opts[:returns]}#{output}"`

Comment: @coderanger now how should i approach this ?

Comment: Ahh okay, I see how this works. So the missing command is a red herring. Try running with `-l debug` on the command line to see the full yum command it is running and the output.